# Why does visual studio 2013 run adb.exe when I try to debug using an android device?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, android-debug, mobile-devices, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have a Sony Xperia Z3 and I'm trying to debug an Apache Cordova application aka: Multi-device hybrid application on my device but visual studio builds and then opens adb.exe after the build is complete. It doesn't launch the application on my device although my device does prompt for verification.

I have developer options enabled on my device and I have USB debugging enabled.

I followed the steps on MSDN to debug an application on my device but it still doesn't work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757059.aspx

I created a self signed keystore using the keytool in jdk and that works fine.

I have all of the necessary drivers installed and my device appears under the "adb devices" list of connected devices.

I tried deleting all the drivers and reinstalling them as well as updating them.

The ripple emulators work perfectly. It's just when I try to debug on a device.

Comment: There was an earlier post that outlined a bunch of steps that helped the user resolve issues deploying to an android device.  I don't know if there are any similarities with your case but it's worth going through that guidance: [VS 2013 Multi Device Hybrid App Failed to deploy to device, no devices found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860043/vs-2013-multi-device-hybrid-app-failed-to-deploy-to-device-no-devices-found)

Answer (score 0):

well, that's a known issue with Cordova visual studio 2013 update. please [see below blog for the known issue list for Cordova](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/cordova-known-issues-vs.aspx) and search for adb on page. you'll get to know about this and there is no fix available for till now. please update me too if you find any :)

Comment: Up till now i still haven't found a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you CANNOT debug a cordova visual studio project in an android DEVICE!  The ripple emulators also are very limited, some plug-ins just simply DON'T work in the emulator!