# Xperia E1 not recognized by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, driver, adb, sony-xperia

I can't seem to make eclipse recognize my Xperia E1 as an ADB device.

The problem is that in the devices list of eclipse it is detected but it says 427ac413 as serial number and the target is unknown. USB Debugging mode is on, I have tried both MSC and MTP modes, I rebooted the device, the ADB Driver is installed from PC Companion (although it says Sony so0107 and not so0101 as I have seen on some other forums). I'm thinking it could either be a driver problem, maybe the wrong one is installed, because the first time I installed it the adb driver said it was from Samsung, and I had to uninstall it and reinstall it.

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546300/3808318). 
The problem was that the SDK_HOME folder wasn't set properly and the PC wasn't authorised. So i disabled developer tools and enabled them again, revoked USB Debugging authorisations and then plugged it back in. The dialog appeared on my phone and then it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps that may work.

1. Turn off the `USB Debugging mode`
2. Connect your phone with both MSC and MTP modes (check that it is accessible in each mode, this means that at least these 2 drivers are fine)
3. Disconnect phone
4. Make sure ADT USB Drivers are up to date.
5. Check that adb is running, better by task manager (If you try at the same time eclipse and cmd adb they mess themselves, red errors about adb start appearing in eclipse console at this case.)
6. Turn on the `USB Debugging mode` on the phone, connect it in MSC.
7. Connect the phone, it should ask for USB debugging access.

---

In case everything fails.

- Try another USB
- Try another USB cable, some idiot phones work better by the "authentic" cable Sony with Sony, Samsung with Samsung etc.
- Restart phone
- Restart computer
- On / Off `USB Debugging mode` with either the phone connected or not.
- Try manually driver installation by pointing the folder of `PC Companion` or `ADB drivers`
- Restart eclipse

---

If still resists, lets make sure that android connects:

- (Close eclipse) Open cmd run adb command
- Connect phone on debug mode `adb devices` check that is online. If yes, its a matter of chance that eclipse recognize it. If no, you may have issues either with adb or with drivers (?).

In case you have issues with adb. Some Companies install an adb in the Phone Suites in order to update phones or access phone data. This adb sets itself in installation at the `PATH` and starts instead of the Android ADB which is for development. In this case you can run in cmd `adb kill-server` navigate to android adb location and `adb.exe start-server`.

In case of the drivers search the net for `Xperia E1 android debug drivers` and start testing if anything works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue can be fixed by manually updating the ADB driver through Windows Device Manager. There is a support thread on the Sony Experia Forum that discusses, and provides detailed steps  for a solution, this issue:

http://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-E-E-dual/ADB-driver-XPERIA-E/td-p/290337

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you may used the wrong driver, try to get it from [here](http://androidxda.com/download-sony-xperia-usb-driver), [here](http://www.driverscape.com/download/xperia-e), or [here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/).

**Then**, force the windows to reinstall the driver again:

- Choose the device from [device manager].
- update driver ----> browse my computer for driver software ----> let me pick from a list... ----> Have Disk.
- Browse and choose the proper driver, the press OK.

**Last**, restart your adb:

- from cmd go to /platform-tools directory then write `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`.