# Getting permission denied error while taking device screenshot from my android device by using UIAUTOMATOR

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am using UIAUTOMATOR for doing uiautomation for android 5.0.1 version.While i am clicking on device screenshot option in UIAUTOMATOR getting this error Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Permission denied.Can anyone guide me what might be the reason for this?

Comment: Without code no one can help you.

Comment: i am not using any code.I connected my device to the system.when i am running 'adb devices' it is showing my device .After that i ran uiautomator.bat under SDK/tools folder .Then Uiautomatorviewer panel is opened and when i clicked on device screenshot (second option) in UIautomator panel it is giving the above error.

Comment: Please check if you have authenticated the device while connecting to the PC. Check this answer [permission issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized)

Comment: Yes i have authenticated the device and my device is rooted also. @SyedMehtab.Can you suggest me any other solution.

Comment: Just try `adb root` and start `uiautomatorviewer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the below steps because my device is rooted.

```
adb root
uiautomatorviewer
```

Thanks to @Rliwan for providing me the solution in comments.Just i want to close the question,so i am posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the 
`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);' into Actvitiy onCreate(),You may encounter this problem.