# react-native :app:installDebug FAILED

Tags: android, react-native

Install APK debug to my device failed.

```
jianglinghuadeMacBook-Pro:hello jianglinghua$ react-native run-android
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
WARNING [Project: :app] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
......
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'MI NOTE LTE - 6.0.1'
Unable to install /Users/jianglinghua/Desktop/hello/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:894)
    ........
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
:app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to establish session

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.945 secs
```

Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
    Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
    set up your Android development environment:
    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

I look at my devices

```
jianglinghuadeMacBook-Pro:hello jianglinghua$ adb devices
List of devices attached
98333978    device
```

Comment: Did you run Yarn before running the project. If yes, can you please let me know if there is any error on that.

Comment: I forgot to replug my phone after restarting my pc, maybe some of you also forgot this.

Answer (score 73):

In my case, I have set up a new app but I was getting errors, tried many possible ways and answers from github and stackoverflow. 
nothing worked

error 
[image]
The solution for me was .. check if you already have an app with the same name is installed in android..

> `Delete old apps and run react-native run-android`

Worked for me.

Comment: This error was created for me too and I did not know the reason for it.
I read your answer. I noticed that in the past, I had a release of the application installed on my mobile. I deleted it and ran the command to run the application again.
The application ran properly on the device

Comment: deleting old apps and running the command works for me but why this is happening .
i used macbook air before so there were no issues like this

Comment: @shailPatel I see, that means this is due to build package setting in react-native. might need to explore react-native repo with this issue. there could be more details if it is listed as an issue.

Answer (score 72):

On my android device, the problem was about the previous build versions of the application that I had installed on my phone before.
the following steps solved my problem:

1. removing any previous build of the application, including debugging version and signed apk version
2. **On windows:**
   On the root directory of your project, run :

```
 cd android
 gradlew clean
 cd ..
 npm cache clean --force
```

**On MacOS or Linux:**
On the root directory of your project, run :

```
 cd android
 ./gradlew clean
 cd ..
```

3. reboot your android device
4. run react-native run-android

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` was an extra step I needed to do in conjunction to `gradlew clean`, deleting the apk, and uninstalling the app on device.

Comment: this works for me because I have created a signed apk of my app. thanks again

Comment: @John: npm cache clean --force this code save my day

Comment: It worked for me reverting from .\gradlew to ./gradlew

Comment: `npm cache clean --force` seems to have fixed it for me on macbook

Answer (score 68):

Since you are using Mi phone which has MIUI

try this

go to Developer options, scroll down to find 'Turn on MIUI optimization' & disable it. Your Phone will be rebooted

check now

---

If you are using any other android phone, which has a custom skin/UI on top of android OS, then try disabling the optimization provided by that UI and check.
(usually you can find that in 'Developer options')

Comment: make sure you have already logged in xiaomi community (mi commnuity) successufly
 `cd android 
 ./gradlew clean 
 cd ..`

Answer (score 30):

I had this issue. Mine worked on the emulator well but it didn't work on the device and the error was

> app:installDebug FAILED.

If you have a different app with the same name (or package name) on the device:
Rename the app or delete it from your device.

Comment: Worked for me, I uninstalled the app from emulator and did npm start (in my case, will be your command in your case) and it worked

Answer (score 26):

This works for me

1. Uninstall the app from your phone
2. cd android
3. gradlew clean
4. cd ..
5. react-native run-android

Comment: In my case the problem appears when I already have an app installed on the devices. So its important to unisntall the old app.

Answer (score 18):

Step 1: Close Android Emulator.

Step 2: Open Android Virtual Device Manager and wipe data by the following image:
[image]

Step 3: Open your terminal and type

```sh
cd android
.\gradlew clean
cd ..
npm cache clean --force
```

Step 4: In terminal, run:

```sh
yarn run android
```

Note: If you are using yarn, just run:

```sh
yarn cache clean
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me. After doing wipe data.

Comment: Today this one saved the day. But all other answers worked for me at one point in past :D.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same problem and did some research. This problem happens a lot on Chinese android phones.

It was solved by change the gradle version to 1.2.3 in file android/build.gradle line 8

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

Comment: its did not work for me, minimum 2.2 is required , I have 2.14.1 installed, i am using Micromax Q348 , its found under adb devices , running 5.1 .

Answer (score 10):

If none of the above solutions works then try the following steps to cold boot the emulator

**open AVD manager -> Edit device -> Show Advanced Settings -> Boot option -> select Cold Boot instead of Quick boot.**

Answer (score 9):

I solved this adding more memory to the device, I did that in this way:

1. Open Android studio
2. click More Actions and open Virtual Device Manager
3. Click the pencil icon
4. Click "Show advance settings"
5. Increase memory in "Internal Storage option"
6. Click "Finish"

Comment: Make sure to restart zour device in case it's already running

Comment: Really works! Although it was not obvious that this can be the reason.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to **android/build.gradle**, change

   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`
    to

   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`
2. Then, go to 
   **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**, 
   change distributionURL to *https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip*
3. Run again.

Answer (score 7):

In my case (with React Native), my Android phone was unrecognized by my PC where I was running the server, which can be seen by the message:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No online devices found.
```

If that is the case, as highlighted in [ADB Android Device Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized), make sure that in Developer Options on your phone **USB Debugging** is set to true, and enter the following commands in terminal or cmd to restart the Android server.

```sh
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

And `adb devices` should list your phone as `device` instead of `unauthorized`

Comment: This works for me. don't need to close the emulators, and just type those two commands will fix the issue

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and I removed the apk file from my android device/emulator and then run react-native run-android and run successfuly .

Comment: This worked for me as well. Opened up list of apps (in my case swipe up from bottom), held on the app, clicked on app info and finally uninstalled.

Comment: Also worked for me but I can imagine it won't work for everyone. Simply uninstalled from the device then tried again. Incredibly simple and quick to do so worth trying first.

Comment: It worked for me,I think you have to do that when you rename the package of the application

Answer (score 6):

I also got troubles with app using gradle 2.14, though with gradle 4 it's ok. By using --deviceID flag app instals without any issue.

```
react-native run-android --deviceId=mydeviceid
```

Comment: how did you get your device id

Comment: adb devices in terminal

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I manually delete the `app-debug.apk` file and run it again.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had the app downloaded from PlayStore and I was trying to debug the APK with the same name. I just uninstalled the app and debugged successfully.

Comment: I also had the release version of the app installed on my phone. Uninstalling it and running `react-native run-android` worked.

Answer (score 5):

cd android and run `./gradlew clean`

After that create a new virtual device that should work

Answer (score 4):

open **avd manager** click on the arrow next to the pencil icon and **wipe data** works for me...

Comment: If still didn't work out, you can create new virtual device as it worked for me.

Comment: yes creating a new virtual works, thanks @RoshanBagde

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete the app from the device.
2. Edit the file (YourAppName -> android -> app -> build.gradle) enter the line below on the defaultConfig field

> multiDexEnabled true

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true //this is the line you need to enter
    applicationId "xxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion xxxxx
    targetSdkVersion xxxxx
    versionCode xx
    versionName "xx"
}
```

3. rebuild the app

Answer (score 4):

For me, restarting my phone did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Android device running out of memory, may be that is the reason.

Comment: Yeah, if none of the above methods work, try to free your memory a bit

Comment: this was the issue for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On MIUI , inside developer option by default "Install via USB" is disabled.Enable it and than it allows installing app via usb.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I did not have enough space on my device to install the app, 
so I cleared up some space and tried again

Comment: Yeah, worked for me two times

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the Developer option in your phone and disable and again enable usb debugging. It will work.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, It is problem of permissions or we can say that setting problem present inside developer options. I am using MI Note 10.To avoid this issue,permit some setting such as common one developer option and USB debugging as well as Install via USB,USB debugging(Security settings), Verify apps over USB.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with wrong AVD settings.
Probably, "Target Android 6.0" was wrong choice.

Next settings were changed to fix ":app:installDebug FAILED" issue:
System Image: Marshmallow , API 23, ABI x86, Target Google API.

see the detail information about this here:
[RN Android Setup](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/android-setup.html)

Answer (score 2):

Previously, I had installed npm and then installed **yarn**, and that is when I started to have problems compiling, even when creating new projects with react-native init . Uninstalling **yarn**, I was able to create and compile.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error but the issue was I did on the **USB Debugging**  after unable this is working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you add more modules to Android, there is an incredible demand placed on the Android build system, and the default memory settings will not work. To avoid `OutOfMemory` errors during Android builds, you should uncomment the alternate Gradle memory setting present in `/android/gradle.properties`:

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

my solution is delete the `android/app/build` folder

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by deleting the current device and just creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

For me I solved it by uninstalling the already existing app from my phone first (which I was working on the day before the day I got this issue) then building again, it happened to me a few times I think that's how I solved it always.

Answer (score 1):

Just lock and unlock the android solved my issue then

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue today, tried many methods online but none of them worked. Here is how I solved this issue:

I used Android Studio to run the app in emulator, it worked. After using `npx react-native run-android` to run (which failed), running using Android Studio directly also failed, and I got the error `INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE`. This message was much more helpful than the error message from react-native. Then I assigned a bigger storage to my virtual Android phone by going to `Device Manager` > `Device Name` > `Edit` > `Show Advanced Settings` > `Internal Storage`. Wipe virtual device's data. Then using the react-native method can work.

```
1. Increase virtual device's internal storage in Android Studio
2. Wipe virtual device's data
3. Run
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying every answer on this thread and many others. Finally what solved it:

1. Go to file > invalidate caches > invalidate and restart.
2. Let the gradle and indexes rebuild fully
3. In device manager > menu > wipe data
4. `npx react-native start --port 8084 --reset-cache`
5. `npx react-native run-android`
6. Try to reapply hair that I have pulled out

Answer (score 0):

Open android studio and check the Device Manager option if you are using a physical device then connect the device. and then run again npm run android .Your app will be running. [image]

Answer (score 0):

if everything was working fine and you got this error suddenly then no need to do anything just open your emulator and do **wipe data**. I had the same problem and fixed it by using this step.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

I just add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

[image]