# Android Emulator with data crashes on launch Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

I created initial project (followed all the steps) by

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

when I run android emulator by:

```
npx react-native start
npx react-native run-android
```

I'm getting this error

```
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
```

As I can see, there's *no metro connection*

When I **wipe data** or reinstall the emulator, it **works fine** for the first time, but when I load the app for the second time, I get this error again

Any ideas how to fix? Many thanks!

Comment: when I run yarn start, run emulator, i can see attached devices ```List of devices attached
emulator-5554 ```

Comment: try reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500205/react-native-appinstalldebug-failed

Comment: @glushkina1 can you please clarify what you mean by wiping the data?

Comment: @ManikKumar when i press the button 'wipe data'

Comment: @L2_Paver I've checked all similar questions, including this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested that version of Android Studio on two more Macbook devices, and all of them had the same issue. Only the new release of Android Studio worked

Answer (score -1):

On the second time,

just run `npx react-native start`, and open the installed app from the emulator. If you see an error connecting to the metro, shake the emulator `Ctrl+M`, it will open the debug menu, change the IP and port to your  IP address, and port as 8081.

Comment: cmd + M works, but there's no input or something in the debug menu, where I could change IP or port. The debug menu has only 'reload' button

Comment: If Ctrl+M for Windows, or Cmd+M for Mac, doesn't open up the debug menu, try long press inside the screen, or run this on terminal `adb shell input keyevent 82`

Comment: @glushkina1, did you try the above things to see if it solved your issue?

Comment: hi, I have checked your solution on 13th of Aug. Debug menu has not got any input, where I could change IP or port. The page has only 'reload' button

Comment: @ glushkina1, can you share the screenshot of the debug menu?