# When should I see 'no device' output when running 'adb devices'?

Tags: android, adb

The adb documentation says that when you issue the `adb devices` command, you get back the state for each device:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#devicestatus

> The connection state of the device can be one of the following: offline, device, no device

When I run `adb devices` without any device connected to my machine, I get this empty result:

> $adb devices
>
> List of devices attached

My question is, under what circumstances can I see the `no device` state when issuing the `adb devices` command? Since if there are no devices, I simply get an empty output, but no `no device` output. The documentation is not clear to me at this part.

Edit:
I am asking this question, because one can also get for example 'unauthorized' state, even though the documentation says nothing about it. So I was curious about this so-called 'no device' state, whether it is a real state, etc.

Comment: I don't understand the reason why you want "no devices" to be seen when an empty message conveys the same meaning

Comment: Yes, when there is no device attached, we get empty result. Don't get confused.

Comment: @cricket_007 I ask this, because one can also get 'unauthorized' state, even though the documentation says nothing about it. So I was curious about this so-called 'no device' state.

Comment: Where have you seen a reference to that?

Comment: To the unauthorized state? I have seen it in my terminal. But here's a SO question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized

Comment: Documentation does not always keep up with reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but one can inspect enough of the `adb` code in a Hex or Text editor to see hard-coded strings.

There are only a handful of instances of `no devices`, but nothing that says "`no device`"

Also highlighted `unauthorized`, which does seem like a conditional when `kick_func_ != null`

```
emulators found�no devices/emulators foundno devices foundmore than one device�more than one emulator�more than one device/emulator�device unauthorized.
�ADB_VENDOR_KEYS�This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is �not set�Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
�Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.�device offline�success�Check failed: kick_func_ != nullptr�offline�unauthorized�
```