# access unauthorized android device from adb shell when device screen broken

Tags: android, shell, adb, data-recovery

I have a broken android phone and I want to get files off of it. Developer mode is enabled, but the screen is broken and I cannot get past the lock screen.

I can boot the device in fastboot or recovery mode.

If I boot normally, I can see the device in adb platform tools by typing `adb devices`. It is listed as `b393b897 unauthorized`.

How can I authorize it? How can I get files off the device? When the screen was not broken - I could simply plug it in via USB, but I had to, on the device screen, switch from debugging to file transfer mode.

I've checked out a ton of [SO articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized), but they all involve doing things on the device itself, which I cannot do (beside boot in fastboot or recovery mode)

I am on a mac osx 10.11.6.

Comment: does your phone support otg

Comment: appears to, yes. It is a OnePlus 2

Comment: use a otg cable and fix a mouse in it you can see a pointer in your screen use the ponter to navigate your phone. Thus you could draw your pattern

Answer (score -2):

You can pull/push files over `ADB` if you have ADB debugging enabled and device drivers are properly installed on your PC.

You should also know the exact file name and file path which you want to extract from your device.

Navigate to adb folder you will find that in your SDK location

Then `adb devices` //to show available devices over ADB

`adb pull /filePath/FileName`

`adb pull /sdcard/temp.jpg` //my file is temp.jpg which is in internal storage

[image]

Comment: Devices won't show up, because of the lock screen, and I can't get past the lock screen because of the damaged screen / thumb print reader.