# how to make android emulator authorized on linux box?

Tags: android, linux

I am developing react-native app and trying to run it on android emulator, which was created in android studio AVD manager.

from the point, where no adb processes are running in system, I am running:

```
$ adb start-server
$ emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_27 -port 5555&
```

Emulator starts successfully, but shows as unauthorized in adb:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5555   unauthorized
```

I tried to revoke USB settings, restart adb server and restarting of emulator, and settings sdk home path in env, but it didn't helped...

How to make in authorized ?

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized

Comment: thanks, I tried this, but unfortunately it didn't helped

Comment: it's said that if your adb can not find your private/public key, it also causes this problem. all information are in that post (in other answers). I think that it covers most cases.

Comment: thanks for hint, it helped !

Comment: you are welcome. if it helped, you can accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: [ADB Android Device Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized)

Please check your Developer Option and  find  “Revoke USB Debugging Authorizations”.

If it doesn't, check your local adb private/public keys. If the keys are missing, it also leads to this error.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of googling and playing with adb keys, solution was to completely remove `/home/user/.android` folder and create new virtual device in android studio