# Phone keeps showing (Allow USB debugging?) dialog with RSA key fingerprint

Tags: android, dialog, adb, usb-debugging, rsa-key-fingerprint

I am using my phone (ASUS Zenfone 551ML) to test android application i am developing.

Working on Android Studio (Version 3.0.1) which is installed on Windows 10.

When i connect the phone to computer, phone keeps showing a dialog carrying a RSA key fingerprint to allow USB debugging.

When i hit OK, after few seconds it appears again hearing windows USB unplug sound, dialog appears again hearing windows USB plug sound.

I am unable to test any app, there's no enough time to install it by android studio at connection intervals .

image : https://image.ibb.co/gwvVJc/image.png

I tried to:

- Check (USB debugging) at {Developer Options}. (ALL THE TIME)
- Use Google USB Driver.
- Reinstall Driver.
- Install ASUS PC link. Well, once i installed this and shared screen to PC, it hasn't disconnected at a long period, I've just tested app at only one session  .
- Change cable (both are original, primary one came with phone's accessories).

Notes :

- When i run "adb devices" it detect my phone as "device" just after i click (OK) at the dialog, Else phone is detected once as "offline" and now as "unauthorized" . And no device is detected while phone unplugged.
- There's no (Select USB configuration) at Developer Options menu, but i've checked Storage>USB computer connection: Connects as MTP.
- I checked : [ADB Android Device Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized) . it's not describing my problem, especially phone got authorized when i push (OK) responding to (Allow USB debugging) dialog. the problem is : that dialog appears constantly.

I hope i can get a solution .

Thanks

Comment: I think I have the same problem, although not as bad as you. The authorization, although using the "Always allow" option, gets requested over and over and over again (several times per day) but I can still debug apps. I also noticed once a different RSA fingerprint, which I rejected and considered very scary. The unplug/plug cycles sound like a weak power or broken or too long cable.

Comment: What i discovered is that Revoking the usb debugging authorisations and not checking the "Always allow from this computer" you will get always the popup. Then i noticed that the key on the popup was different half of the times, and one of those never worked, while the other one always worked. Very annoying