# Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: This computer is not authorized to debug the device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using a Pixal 2XL and I'm running Windows 10. I am using Expo and Visual Studio Code to develop.

I've enabled developer options and I've enabled USB debugging. I was able to run the application on my phone about a month ago however now it doesn't work. Recently my phone did an update so I'm unsure if that caused this error.

I've already looked for solutions and non of them worked. I've tried turning on developer options on and off and I've tried revoking all authorizations.

I'm not using genymotion, Android Studio, or an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the device is no longer authorized on ADB for whatever reason.

Here is the answer to similar question.

[ADB Android Device Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized)

Comment: I'm not using android studio though

Comment: @Lonstu. can you plug in your device into your computer and start your terminal and then execute bash 'adb devices'? and show me the result.

Comment: PS C:\Users\me\Documents\Personal Projects\React Native\project1> bash 'adb devices' /usr/bin/bash: adb devices: No such file or directory

Comment: I think you have to add the location of adb to your bash_profile. Have you downloaded adb?

Comment: I have not downloaded adb. I've been able to get React Native Apps working on my phone for months now, and I've never had to authorize my computer before