# Samsung Adb after a few days becomes un-authorized ; kill-server won't work

Tags: android, security, debugging, usb, adb

I am communicating via desktop to a Samsung Android phone. OS is latest. I have done "Allow always" on the same desktop I use every day for authorization of the key for secure debugging. But to my surprise, I keep getting pop-up authorization message on the phone after a few days. I do not want to kill-server all the time to make it work or anything. However, I have restarted the phone as well. My USB cable is perfect. Why is the certificate getting revoked and I have to authorize again after a few days?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There a wide variety of possible issues with ADB authorization. You might have multiple Android SDK installs on your path, you might have bad permissions in your `~./android` folder. There's a ton of answers here that might give you some ideas of where to look from the problem [ADB Android Device Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized)

Also instead of killing the server you might be able to turn USB debugging on and off to circumvent this issue as well (though this is still tedious)