# Any hope for turning on phone Nokia 7.1 using adb

Tags: adb

My power button died on my phone. Or got less and less responsive. Last time I was lucky that trying a long time I managed to start up my phone. Since then I kept my phone on perpetually or restarting it if that was required. However, now my phone just suddenly turned off out of nowhere. I tried to turn it on again but had no luck. I had previously turned on USB debugging since I thought that was enough to turn it on from the pc if it ever got turned off. Now it seems that was not enough as it shows up as unauthorized in `adb` (I never tried actually connecting, very stupid on my part). Is there any hope for turning my device on through `adb`.

Phone: Nokia 7.1

---

There are some questions on problems with unauthorized devices ([ADB Android Device Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized)) but those seem to assume I can still turn on my phone to change settings. Is it impossible otherwise?

Comment: if you cannot connect thur adb, type to see whether it is responsive on fastboot (connect by USB cable, then type fastboot devices) Let us know the result

Comment: @Ken, unfortunately it does not show up in fastboot devices at all

Comment: if everything fails, please try to CAREFULLY remove the phone case, and you shall be able to see the power on button. try to switch it on.

Answer (score 0):

*tldr;* Here is a detailed list of instructions if you want to try your luck with `fastboot`. Your touchscreen and volume buttons must be functional for this to work.

- Make sure the phone is turned off.
- Press and hold the Volume Down button. Don't release it.
- Plug in a USB charging cable
- When the screen turns on and shows a message saying "Download" or "Fastboot" mode, release the Volume Down button.
- Charge your phone like this for 2 minutes, to make sure it has enough charge.
- Move your phone's USB cable and connect it to a PC.
- [Download the binary for `fastboot`](https://wiki.lineageos.org/adb_fastboot_guide.html).
- Run `fastboot continue`.