# Android prevents PC from installing APKs by default

Tags: android, debugging, usb, settings

I've just run an APK installation via Android Studio in my Redmi Note 7 but ended up making a fool mistake. When a dialog popped asking me if I wanted to allow the installation, I checked the "remember my choice" box but accidentally refused permission. So now I'm not being able to run my APKs through PC because I can't find any option to reset these choices.

In debug section of developer options, I've tried to uncheck e and check again "install via USB", "USB debugging (security settings)" (not sure if is written that way in English) and revoked USB debugging authorizations. I've also cleared settings app data. None of these steps solved the problem.

Am I really going to have to reset my phone to factory defaults? Isn't there a file I can delete or something? What a stupid misclick...

Comment: Try 1) [stop and restart your `adb server`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093170/295004). 2) [Remove old `adb` keys and create new ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243629/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Unfortunately, these steps have not fixed my issue.